# Architecture of a Xamarin app, communicating with a web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As described in the headline I want to build a Xamarin Forms app which is communicating with a web server. On the client side I am using the `MMVM` pattern of course.

Here my question: what about the communication with the server? From my point of view the server should nothing know about the concrete client technology (`INotifyPropertyChanged` e.g), so in this layer I still have to apply the `MVC` pattern for communication, right?

What costs me sleep on this approach is that I need to convert the objects 2 times in every direction:
`Entity <--> MVC-Model (Dto) <--> MVVM-ViewModel`

Am I right with my assumption or completely off the track?

Comment: Yes. I think you'll want a DTO object to communicate between the systems and convert into their own framework specific layers.

Comment: DTO is part of the M(odel) in both the MVVM and MVC patterns. INotifyPropertyChanged is part of the ViewModel in MVVM. Even though you will need to write code to wrap DTO(s) inside a VM the time is (more or less) saved in less Controller code. With Forms you don't need a controller and could skip the VM and just use View (XF View) as the VM replacement but then you will not be able to reuse the code on platforms that don't have Forms support. If you decide to write a complete VM then it is easy to reuse elsewhere (e.g. WPF, Razor).

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to create a WebAPI which you then call from your view model in your shared Xamarin Forms project.

```
public class CommunicationService<T> where T : class
{
    public CommunicationService ()
    { 
    }

    public async Task<T> GetRequestAsync (string url)
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient ();
        var response = await client.GetAsync (url);
        var responseResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> (responseResult); 
        return result; 
    }
}
```

From my view model I then call my function using the code below:

```
var communicationService = new CommunicationService<List<MyDtoModel>> ();    
var items = await communicationService.GetRequestAsync (@"http://myurl.com/api/controller/action");
```

Then you can use AutoMapper to map the result to your view model, or of course, use the DTO directly, even if that not is best practice for the MVVM pattern.